# Почему смешались поля двух обьектов выводе?

Tags: python

Есть простой код.

```
class User:


    profile={}
    def __init__(self,name,lastname,**profile):
        self.profile["firstName"]=name
        self.profile['lastname']=lastname



        for key,value in profile.items():
            self.profile[key]=value


    def describe_user(self,):
         for k,v in self.profile.items():
             print(k, v,)



user=User('Петя','Смирнов',location='Питер',возраст= "39")


user.describe_user()
```

```
class SuperUser(User):
    def __init__(self,name,lastname,**profile):
        super().__init__(name,lastname,**profile)

superUser=SuperUser('Семен','Семеныч',location='Sweden',age='42')

superUser.describe_user()
```

Почему в выводе на печать у  экземпляра субкласса инициализировано поле возраст ? Причем инициализировано значением экземпляра суперкласса.

Answer (score 3):

Потому что `User.profile` один для всех экземпляров. Вы определили profile на уровне класса.

Поместите `self.profile = {}` внутрь `__init__()` метода, чтобы для каждого объекта свой profile словарь создать.

Comment: Блин,не могу вкурить, обьектную модель питона после java. У меня каким то образом получилось статическое свойство?

Comment: @RVG Питон не Java. Не стоит пытаться из Java терминологию использовать в случаях когда что-то не работает (поведение может быть похожее, но отличаться в какой-то детали, скрывая ошибку). Переменные на уровне класса являются *атрибутами класса*, общими для всех экземпляров. Также как и с *атрибутами экземпляра* может быть использована `self.profile` нотация. Чтобы создать атрибут экземпляра, поместите `self.profile = {}` *внутрь* метода. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#class