# Класс элемента атрибутного дерева: где зацикливается метод dump()?

Tags: python

```
class Sym:
    val = ''
    tag = 'sym'

    def __init__(self, V): 
        self.val = V

    nest = []

    def push(self, o): 
        self.nest.append(o) 
        return self

    def __repr__(self): 
        return self.dump()

    def head(self): 
        return "<" + self.tag + ":" + self.val + ">"

    def pad(self, N): 
        return '\t' * N

    def dump(self, depth=0):
        S = "\n" + self.pad(depth) + self.head()
        for i in self.nest: S += i.dump(depth+1)
        return S

print Sym('symbol').push(Sym('+'))
```

Comment: Может тут? `for i in self.nest: S += i.dump(depth+1)`. Тут идет перебор по `self.nest`

Comment: естественно, но не вижу никакого криминала, обычная рекурсия, аналог на С++ работает без вопросов

Answer (score -1):

Проблема в том, что поля объявленные в теле описания класса, являются **статическими**. Т.е. nest[] в sym:+ будет включать и sym:symbol, и возникает бесконечная рекурсия.

Исправлено:

```
class Sym:
#del     val = ''
    def __init__(self, V): self.val = V; self.nest=[]
#del     nest = []
```

Comment: В Питоне нет "статических" полей. Термины здесь: атрибуты класса (общие для всех экземпляров класса) и атрибуты экземпляра (у каждого свои). К обоим можно обращаться используя `self.nest` синтаксис. Проблема у вас что Sym.nest это атрибут класса, а не экземпляра. Перенесите создание атрибута внутрь метода (`__init__`). Связанный вопрос: [Почему смешались поля двух обьектов выводе?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/612702/23044)